# Get previous row value by group after condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following problem. This is my dataframe:

```
district    curfew_name        active   value    date
  A            np.nan            0       10       1
  A             B1               1       20       4
  A             B1               1       21       6
  C             D1               1       14       8      
  C             D1               1       16       11
  C             D2               1       14       13
  E             F1               0       30       10
  E             F1               1       14       12
```

So, each row is a date (2-3 days between each row), in which `district` might have a curfew activated.  So I want to know for each curfew, what was the `value` column's value for that district the date before the first activation of said curfew. So, in this case, curfew `B1` gets activated on date `4`, so I check the previous `value` for that district and it's 10. For curfew `D1` I don't know what's the previous `value` for that district, so I would get a `nan`. For `D2` the previous value is `D1`'s last value: 16. Finally, for `F1` we see it was announced beforehand, so we get a 0 before it is active. The value would be 30, anyways. So, my final `Series` would look like this:

```
curfew_name    previous_value
    B1              10
    D1             np.nan
    D2              16
    F1              30
```

So, I can get each curfew's first appearance like this:

```
df[df.active.eq(1)].reset_index().groupby('curfew_name').first()['index']
```

And then I simply tried substracting one, and then extracting those indexes:

```
idx = df[df.active.eq(1)].reset_index().groupby('curfew_name').first()['index'] - 1
```

But for cases like `D1` this would get me a `21` which is a value from another district. How would you go about it?  I've tried some combinations of `groupby('district')` , `shift()`, `eq()`, but I'm still not making it in an efficient way.

Thanks !

Edit: my approach for now would be to get the previous index, then check if the row associated with that index is in the same district than the original index and filter those when that condition is met, but I'm quite sure I can do something better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(df.assign(previous_value=df.groupby('district').value.shift())  # usual groupby.shift
   .drop_duplicates(['district','curfew_name'])                  # drop all duplicates
  [['curfew_name','previous_value']]                             # select the columns of interest
   .dropna(subset=['curfew_name'])                               # ignore curfew with nan values
)
```

Output:

```
  curfew_name  previous_value
1          B1            10.0
3          D1             NaN
5          D2            16.0
7          F1            30.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang! It seems my example didn't completely cover possible cases, so I'll update accordingly. The gist of it is that curfews are sometimes declared in advance so `curfew_name` might have `active` as zero, before activating

Comment: I managed to do it, getting inspiration from your answer! I'll post what I did, but I'm not sure why your option didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Getting inspiration from @Quang Hoang's answer and my initial approach I managed to do it:

```
df['previous_value'] = df.groupby('district').value.shift()
idx = df[df.active.eq(1)].reset_index().groupby('curfew_name').first()['index']
previous_values = df[df.index.isin(idx )].set_index('curfew_name').previous_value
```